# Setting a row to a variable

Tags: mysql

I couldn't seem to find any other questions similar to mine that would help me. I'm brand new to this, so please excuse any mistakes I may be making. I'm trying to set a row to a variable so I can add 1 to it each time the page is reached [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V5gk.png) an example of the rows I have. The error it gives me is this:

> Error updating record: 
>   Unknown column '' in 'field list'

```
<?php
    $vote = $_POST["votes"];
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","eaxmple2ows0ff","","my_eaxmple2ows0ff");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    $sql = "UPDATE `my_eaxmple2ows0ff`.`HoR Candidates` SET `$vote` = '$vote+1' WHERE `HoR Candidates`.`id` = 2";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<br>Record updated successfully <br>";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Error updating record: <br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There looks like a error in your MySQL Query,

```
"UPDATE `my_eaxmple2ows0ff`.`HoR Candidates` SET `$vote` = '$vote+1' WHERE `HoR Candidates`.`id` = 2";
```

it should be `SET votes = votes + 1` That will increment the column value by 1.
You seem to be trying to load $vote from the page and increment it in the query from there but from what I think you are trying to do its not neccesary.

The format of SET should be `SET ColumnName = Value`